# Is A ⊥ B | C where one path active but another inactive?

Tags: graphical-model, separation

[image]

I'm trying to determine if A ⊥ B | C?

I see two paths flowing through elements of C:

(1) B <- C - > A (all variables unobserved, active triple; independence cannot be guaranteed for this path)

(2) B -> C <- A (all variables unobserved, inactive triple; independence can be guaranteed)

Provided that there are two paths connecting A and B via C, where one is active and the other is inactive, I'm not sure what the "real" answer is?

Does only path need to be inactive? 
Or do both paths need to be inactive?